# Где скачать исходники Android SDK?

Tags: android, java

Где скачать исходный код (не class-файлы) Android SDK? Вижу только скомпилированные версии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы смотреть онлайн, загляните сюда: [SDK](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=summary). А чтобы скачать к себе, выполните

```
git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/sdk.git
```

Comment: Кстати, Гугл открыл код последней версии Андроид?

Answer (score 1):

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html